# Flex: Tab Navigator tab position

Tags: apache-flex, layout, tabs, tabnavigator

I need to develop a Tab Navigator with a few tabs on the left hand side and one tab on the right hand side, I have experimented with the "tabOffset" property, but this does not seem to be able to help

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to be sure you are using Flex 3, right? Maybe by any chance you can use spark components?

Comment: The project that we are busy with was started a long time ago, and was written in Flex 3, so we are trying to stick to it, but yes i am aware that i should be using flex 4.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made custom TabNavigator component.

```
package
{
import mx.containers.TabNavigator;
import mx.controls.Button;
import mx.events.FlexEvent;

public class CustomTabNavigator extends TabNavigator
{
    public function CustomTabNavigator()
    {
        super();
    }

    override protected function createChildren(): void
    {
        super.createChildren();
        tabBar.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, addSpacer);
    }

    public function addSpacer(event: FlexEvent): void
    {
        var buttonCount: int = tabBar.getChildren().length;

        var _width : Number = this.width;
        var button: Button = tabBar.getChildAt(buttonCount-1) as Button;

        _width = _width - button.width;
        button.x = _width;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, Thanks! I did not use your exact method, but the concept was the same, i just set the last button's x property within the on_complete method.

Comment: You are right! My code had a bug. Set the last button's x propertiy is correct. Thanks!